# define bindings of map a into map b

Tags: keymap

I am trying to write the following function:

```
(defun define-keymap-onto-keymap (from-map to-map)
  (map-keymap
   (lambda (key cmd) (define-key to-map key cmd))
   from-map))
```

My implementation above does not work in general, since
the `key` argument to map-keymap is not a key,
but an event, which is not always understood by `define-key`. For example:

```
(define-keymap-onto-keymap
 (let ((kmap (make-sparse-keymap)))
   (define-key kmap (kbd "<s-return>") nil)
   kmap)
 emacs-lisp-mode-map)
*** Eval error ***  Wrong type argument: arrayp, s-return
```

Also:

```
(define-keymap-onto-keymap
 (let ((kmap (make-sparse-keymap)))
   (define-key kmap (kbd "s-2") nil)
   kmap)
 emacs-lisp-mode-map)
*** Eval error ***  Wrong type argument: arrayp, 8388658
```

Is there a
function similar to define-key, which understands whatever may be
the type of `key`?

I am not interested in solutions like `derived-mode-merge-keymaps`, which use

```
(setcdr (nthcdr (1- (length new)) new) old)
```

which can result in infinite lists, and I'm not interested in a brand-new copy of `from-map`,
like in `keymap--merge-bindings` but to add
bindings to an existing `to-map`.

Can I just append `from-map` onto `to-map`?

Comment: Are you interested in `set-keymap-parent`?

Comment: @npostavs I get several errors like ` Wrong type argument: arrayp, menu-bar`, `Wrong type argument: arrayp, 8388703`, `Wrong type argument: arrayp, s-return`

Comment: @npostavs can a keymap have multiple parents? I am trying to extend a keymap like `emacs-lisp-mode-map` with a keymap I've created.

Comment: Regarding `arrayp` errors, you're missing a call to `vector`, try `(lambda (key cmd) (define-key to-map (vector key) cmd))`.

Comment: Regarding multiple parents, see the bottom of [(elisp) Inheritance and Keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Inheritance-and-Keymaps.html)

Comment: why don't I need the (vector key) when defining the key into the first map?

Comment: @npostavs would you mind adding your suggestion as a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the effect you want by setting a keymap's parent, see [(elisp) Inheritance and Keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Inheritance-and-Keymaps.html)

```
A keymap can inherit the bindings of another keymap, which we call the
"parent keymap".  Such a keymap looks like this:

     (keymap ELEMENTS... . PARENT-KEYMAP)

The effect is that this keymap inherits all the bindings of
PARENT-KEYMAP, whatever they may be at the time a key is looked up, but
can add to them or override them with ELEMENTS.
```

> can a keymap have multiple parents?

```
   Sometimes you want to make a keymap that inherits from more than one
map.  You can use the function ‘make-composed-keymap’ for this.

 -- Function: make-composed-keymap maps &optional parent
     This function returns a new keymap composed of the existing
     keymap(s) MAPS, and optionally inheriting from a parent keymap
     PARENT.[...]

For example, here is how Emacs sets the parent of ‘help-mode-map’, such
that it inherits from both ‘button-buffer-map’ and ‘special-mode-map’:

     (defvar help-mode-map
       (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
         (set-keymap-parent map
           (make-composed-keymap button-buffer-map special-mode-map))
         ... map) ... )
```

---

The main problem with your original code is that a binding passed to `define-key` must be a key sequence, see [(elisp) Key Sequences](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Sequences.html)):

```
A "key sequence", or "key" for short, is a sequence of one or more input
events that form a unit.  Input events include characters, function
keys, mouse actions, or system events external to Emacs, such as
‘iconify-frame’ (see Input Events).  The Emacs Lisp representation
for a key sequence is a string or vector.
[...]
   Key sequences containing function keys, mouse button events, system
events, or non-ASCII characters such as ‘C-=’ or ‘H-a’ cannot be
represented as strings; they have to be represented as vectors.
```

Whereas, `map-keymap` gives single events:

```
(map-keymap FUNCTION KEYMAP)

Call FUNCTION once for each event binding in KEYMAP.
FUNCTION is called with two arguments: the event that is bound, and
the definition it is bound to.  The event may be a character range.
```

So your code should look more like this:

```el
(map-keymap
   ;; FIXME: also handle case where KEY is a range.
   (lambda (key cmd) (define-key to-map (vector key) cmd))
   from-map)
```

> why don't I need the `(vector key)` when defining the key into the first map?

`(kbd "<s-return>")` gives `[s-return]`, a vector.